# grails unit-test domain objects list function

Tags: java, unit-testing, grails

I have small function like

```
def listUser() {
    List<User> user = User.list(max:10 )
    render(view: '/user/listUser', model:[user: user])
}
```

but I failed to write unit testing for this function, I tried with

```
def "test list User"() {
    User user = User.build(userName:'testUser')
    User.metaClass.list() >> [user]

    when:
        List<User> users = controller.listUser()

    then:
        users.size() == 10
}
```

but it is throwing `java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot invoke method size() on null object`. Can someone help me in this? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This resolves my issue.

```
User.metaClass.'static'.list = { ->
        [new User(userName: "Suganthan")]
    }
```